# How to remove specific data from sending email

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, email, variables

I am working on php form which will collect OID and will sent as email from a device and its working fine, I need assistance only for removing some specific data, ex: if specific OID is not available my variable will detect as "Not available" and I am receiving email as the same. is it possible to search and remove "Not available" word from my form before sending as email.

from below code kindly assume that "$FaultNo002" detect as Not available.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$FaultNo001 = $_POST['FaultNo001'];
$FaultNo002 = $_POST['FaultNo002'];



$body = "
<html>
<body>
<table width='750' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'><h1>&nbsp;Fault Codes</h1><hr></td>
    </tr>
  <tr><td>
  ".$FaultNo001."
  ".$FaultNo002."

  </td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>

";


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->From = from@mail.com;
$mail->FromName = name;
$mail->addAddress('to@mail.com', 'test');     
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->Body    = $body;




?>
```

Waiting for your support, kindly let me know if you didn't understand my question.

My form in below

```
<form action="https://domain/Fault_Mail.php" method="post" id="Form">
<input type="text" readonly id="FaultNo001" style="background:none; border: 0;" class="Font4" value="Not Availables1" name="FaultNo001" size="100">
<input type="text" readonly id="FaultNo002" style="background:none; border: 0;" class="Font4" value="" name="FaultNo002" size="100">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="SubmitButton" border="2" >
</form>
```

Comment: If it is a form input value, you could check it the given input field contains the value "Not available", and if so prevent the system to even post the form

Comment: yes it is input value, and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$mail->Body    = str_replace('Not available','',$body);`

but consider preventing to send this value. If you later decide to change the value in the form (why not numeric) or if you translate to another language, you have to change this line of code as well

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but still didn't work

Comment: @SajeedThajudeen it's because `str_replace` is case sensitive, try `str_ireplace`

Comment: @Idle001 Still not work for me, is there is any other way?

Comment: the value in the form is `Not Availables1` using str_ireplace() would still leave "s1" in place. But the rest should have been removed. (any extra whitespaces maybe?

Comment: @Ivo P It's working, earlier it was my mistake didn't updated properly.. Thanks a lot